# Remove all the . (dots) from a string except the last one

Tags: powershell

I need to remove all dots in a string, except last one.
For example if string is '1.2.3.4.5"  the results needs to be "1234.5"
This is in powershell. I am not able to do it.

Thank you in advance,

Comment: Can you post the code you wrote to attempt it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

RegEx Replace (all dots not followed by a dot)

```
"1.2.3.4" -replace "\.(?=.*\.)", ""
```

Comment: This can be shortened to: `"1.2.3.4" -replace "\.(?=.*\.)"`

Answer (score 1):

I think this does the trick:

```
function RemoveAllExceptLastDot ($inputString)
{
    $currentString = $inputString;

    while ($currentString.Split('.').Length -gt 2)
    {
        $indexOfFirstDot = $currentString.IndexOf('.');
        $currentString = $currentString.Substring(0, $indexOfFirstDot) + $currentString.Substring($indexOfFirstDot + 1, $currentString.Length - $indexOfFirstDot - 1);
    }

    Write-Output $currentString;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you want to do this for a filename, this one might be easier to remember. It doesn't use RegEx, just good old [`String.Replace()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.replace?view=net-5.0)

```
$fi = [io.fileinfo] 'foo.bar.txt'
$fi.BaseName.Replace('.', '') + $fi.Extension
```

You don't need the cast when you are operating on existing files like this:

```
Get-ChildItem . | Foreach-Object {
    $_.BaseName.Replace('.', '') + $_.Extension
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this as filedot being input and file being output

```
@powershell "(GC .\filedot.txt)|%%{$_ -Replace '\.'}|SC .\file.txt"
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).