# powershell replace with exception

Tags: powershell

I would like to change a file name.
All dots in the name must be replaced by underscores. The exception is the last dot in the sentence, which is the one for the file extension.

```
Example:  123jhkgbiiw.erffg.wsf.txt = 123jhkgbiiw_erffg_wsf.txt
```

I have the beginning for the replacement. Unfortunately I don't know how to get the exception right

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace '.', '_'}
```

Thanks already for your help

Comment: Instead of `$_.Name` you should use `$_.BaseName` what's the name of the file without the extension. ;-)

Comment: Thanks I will change it but it does not solve my problem ;-)

Comment: Why not? The *last dot* belongs to the extension - not to the BaseName property.

Comment: The second issue is that you can't use literal dot. You have to escape it for use in regular expression: `\.`. Your current code replaces _all_ characters by `_` ;-)

Comment: @zett42  ... totally missed that one ... you're perfectly right (as usual). ;-)

Comment: if I try the following code I get only underlines:                                                                `dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.BaseName -replace '\.', '_'}`

Comment: This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28500532/remove-all-the-dots-from-a-string-except-the-last-one.  You can simply use RegEx.

Comment: I've added another answer to the linked dupe, that might be easier to remember (no RegEx): https://stackoverflow.com/a/66207681/7571258

Answer (score 0):

The correct code for this is:

```
dir | rename-item -NewName {$_.Name -replace "\.(?=.*\.)", "_"}
```